# making settings value persistent

Tags: vb.net, winforms, settings, persistent

can anyone help me with how to make the settings in my app persistent
When i save in the previous run using this

```
my.Settings.setting_name= some_value
my.Settings.save()
```

when getting the values using this

```
some_value=my.Settings.setting_name
```

i still see the old values in the IDE settings options
How can i make the changes reflect even in the vs ide

thanks

Comment: This link help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwc80dzb(v=vs.80).aspx

Are your settings User or Application? If they are Application-scope then you can not save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE will always show the default settings for your application which it copies to .exe.config file in the same folder as your executable.  At runtime, the `Settings.Save()` call will save the new settings in a *User.Config* file located in 'UserProfile'\Application Data\'Company_Name'\_mangled\Version\ folder.

I'm on Windows XP and other versions may be different.

Comment: when i open that file you mentioned., after several run, it was default value or empty

Comment: In the IDE when you view the settings, are they defined with User scope?

Comment: i decided to use another form of setting anyway. thanks for contribbuting